# How do I backup computer that wont let me go on windows from usb hard drive with ubuntu?

Tags: usb, backup, laptop

I am having an issue with my laptop and it won't let me turn it on. It goes straight to "preparing automatic restart" and then it gives me a blue screen with aload of options. Ive tried all of them and no success! So basically it won't let me on that laptop. I have rung up the experts and they have recommended me to this software! I am trying to backup the files I have on my broken laptop by getting Ubuntu onto a usb and transfering data through that!? I don't know if this is an obvious one or isn't possible but the expert dude said that kind of thing! So overall how do i back it up with ubuntu?!?!? Sorry if you don't understand me just leave a comment and I'll get back to you asap.

Thanks, Mr Bombastic

Answer (score 0):

You will need an Ubuntu Desktop install image.  You will need to boot to this image instead of your hard drive and use Ubuntu to offload you files to another device like a USB drive.  Here are the steps:

1. Download the [Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop image here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=16.04&architecture=amd64)  You will need to [create a bootable USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) or [burn it to a CD.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)
2. Insert your shiny new installer media and fire up your machine.  Chances are it will boot to your media automatically.  If not you need to determine what keystroke is needed to select a boot device.
3. Let the Ubuntu Live Installer boot up and select "Try Ubuntu" from the menu that pops up.
4. Connect the device that you want to copy your data to.  It should show up on the desktop as a hard drive icon.

Click on the file cabinet on the left hand side.  You should see 3 drive entries.

[image]

Mine is a VM and doesn't have any additional drives attached,  but it should look like that image.  Yours will have 3 drives listed instead of just one:

- Computer:  The live Ubuntu OS that you are looking at.
- USB Drive:  The drive you want to copy your files to.
- Windows Drive:  Your broken install that you want to copy from.

  5. Open your Windows drive by double clicking on it, select the files you need to keep, right click and select `copy`, Right click on your USB Drive and select `paste`.  You files should start moving over to the USB drive.

Once your files are copied over, go ahead and close those windows, double click the "Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" icon and follow the instructions to install Ubuntu.  Try it.  You'll like it.  [Here is the official installation guide.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

You are already a member of the community, so if you get stuck just come back here and ask a question again.

Now you can put your files wherever you want to.

:)

Comment: Okay thanks, alot of technical info there lol! I will try my best to follow your guide. Thanks vm!

Comment: Be sure to vote up and accept my answer if it works for you.  Thanks.